# Partial View Refresh and Script Doesnt Work

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

In my C# MVC4 application, I have a partial view that contains these two scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.rowselection').click(function (e) {
            var tdata = $('#form1').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: tdata,
                url: "/Home/PartialAverage",
                success: function (result) { success(result); }
            });
        });

        function success(result) {
            $("#Display_Average").html(result);
        }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('.AVEexists').length) {
            $('#SubmitButton').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

When the partial view is refreshed the first script still works as desired.  The second script however, does not appear to work because the button which is hidden correctly the first time the partial is loaded does not reappear when the partial is refreshed and not containing any elements with the class .AVEexists

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your whole partial view? Or are those .AVEexists elements inside this partial view?
And if the submit button is outside your partial view, shouldn't you be doing

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.AVEexists').length) {
        $('#SubmitButton').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#SubmitButton').show();
    }

});
```

in the second script?

Comment: Don't know why I was overlooking it, but yes the button was in another partial view that contained the partial view with the script.  Adding the else statement caused the functionality to work as desired.  In answer to the first question, the .AVEexists elements were inside the view with the script.